# Please vote on this proposal for a literary criticism site!

Tags: discussion

Alright friends, there are many people coming to Writers to ask for feedback on their own writing. They often try to cloak this objective by asking a more generally applicable question, but quite often it is clear that what they really want is plain old constructive criticism.

Criticism is off topic on Writers, but there is no reason it could not have its own Stack Exchange site. And in fact there is a site proposal that fills just that need:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82417/literature-review

Why don't we all go over there and follow and vote to make it happen?

And if anyone asks for feedback again, instead of just sending them away, please post a link to that proposal in the close reasons, so they can also go there and help get the site underway that they want.

Thank you.

Comment: done, and thanks letting us know.